# Bootstrap - inline-list stacks instead of lining-up horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site that uses Bootstrap 3. In that site, I have a list of items. For each item, I want to show an icon. To the right of the icon, I want to show a blurb of text. Currently, I have this working for small amounts of text. However, when my block of text grows, it eventually gets to a point where the text block appears below the icon instead of beside it.

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5ms53qjc/1/). The code looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li>[icon]</li>
        <li><div style="background-color:#ccc; padding:16px;">
           This is some text that should appear to the right of the icon.
           If this text is longer, it should wrap within this box.
        </div></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>   

  <br />

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li>[icon]</li>
        <li><div style="background-color:#ccc; padding:16px;">
            Shorter blurbs appear beside like it should.
        </div></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>   

</div>
```

Why isn't the second `li` always appearing to the right of the first `li`?

Comment: Well, when you fill up an `inline-block` element to 100% width, it's going to push everything else out of the way. That's the `block` portion of `inline-block` at work. An idea might be to put `col-xs-1` on your icon <li> and `col-xs-11` on your <li> text, though I personally would hunt for something better. What may also be better is using the [<dl> element](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#horizontal-description).

Comment: @DrewKennedy You should post that as an answer ;) Especially the `<dl>` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making `li`elements appearing side to side. Use the existing component of bootstrap `Media object`(more info [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media)) to make it happen.

Check Demo **[Here](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/ZpkmwZ?editors=1100)**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="media-object">
      <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
      </span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4> This is some text that should appear to the right of the icon. If this text is longer, it should wrap within this box.
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```